# GreenPlum loading utility gpfdist syntax problem

Tags: greenplum

Hi I'm learning greemplum and using gpfdist to loading files, however there are some syntax that I couldn't find explanations on docs.

```
gpfdist -d ~/gpdb-sandbox-tutorials/faa -p 8081 > /tmp/gpfdist.log 2>&1 &
```

The above is the example, I would like to ask

1. What does ">" means
2. What does "2>&1" means
3. At the end "&" means?

Can anyone tell me the detail of how these syntax works.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does ">" means

This redirects standard out (stdout) to a file (gpfdist.log).

> What does "2>&1" means

This redirects standard error (stderr) to stdout so that errors are also logged to the same file normal messages are sent.

> At the end "&" means?

This means run the program in the background.

This is all standard Unix stuff and not directly related to gpfdist.